# PHP session save path?

Tags: php, session

why we change the php default session path to user defined session path.
Like i have checked in some plugin the session path is changed like this

```
session_save_path(ABSPATH ."sessions");
```

what are the benefits by using this approach and what happens if i remove this line to save the sessions in the default way ?

Comment: It sort of depends what `ABSPATH` is set to?

Comment: On shared hosting servers, there may be some malconfigured servers where other users may gain access to your session files (and so steal your sessions). By changing the session sve path to a directory where just you have acces, this may not happen anymore.

Comment: @Christian as you have mentioned that this may not happen anymore. so can it is save to update the path to php defaults ?

Comment: Well, no, if you do that, every app saves their sessions there. For security reasons, it's best to define it just app-wide.

Comment: @Christian thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Then you have another directory, it won't be deleted session file from server then it will clean default session folder. And one more you can manipulate which session is important and which is not. Sample: for Admin you save in admin directory and delete those never and for Other_users you create other directory which will be cleaned in 5 days for sample.